# Trigger publish as part of deployment

Tags: powershell, deployment

We have a set up with CM, CD1, CD2.  Both CDs have their own 'web' database (cd1 and cd2).

We are currently using DevOps to run a powershell script that deploys to each machine.  We would like to include a line in the CD deployments to publish to their respective db.

What is the best way to do this?  (9.2)

Comment: Do you have an example script you can add to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the logical idea [Unicorn](https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn) has:

- Create a dedicated handler/page to trigger publish (similar to `unicorn.aspx`)
- Place the `trigger publish` logic inside to start publishing to given targets
- Use `secret token concept` that must be embedded into the request to trigger publish

Implementing it as a `legal` page would force Sitecore to start, therefore allowing you to execute publishing operation.

Comment: How would I call that from my script?

Comment: Plain get request during build, like mysite.com/autopublish.aspx?token=xxx

Answer (score 0):

In your CI-CD pipeline, you can call the below URL to trigger the auto publishing.

```
https://<sitecore_instance>/unicorn.aspx?verb=Sync&log=Debug&skipTransparentConfigs=false&sc_lang=en
```

Actually, the below command is for performing unicorn sync. Publishing should be happening after completing the sync activity.

So please make sure your environment is configured for triggering autopublishing once the sync is complete. To make sure of this, please check the below file. It should not be disabled.

```
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/<sitecore_instance>/App_Config/Include/Unicorn/Unicorn.AutoPublish.config
```